# Get value from \foreach

Tags: foreach, loops, etoolbox

I build a macro named `\fromlist` to get value from a list. The value can be typeset, but can not be invoked directly, why and how to deal with it?

Code：

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt


\begin{document}

\newcommand\fromlist[2]{%
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in #1{%
    \ifnum\i=#2 \x\breakforeach\fi%
  }%
}

% Test:
\def\bbb{2in}\rule{\bbb}{5pt} % This ok.
\def\bbb{\fromlist{{1in,2in,3in}}{2}}\bbb %This is ok.
\rule{\fromlist{{1in,2in,3in}}{2}}{5pt} % This causes error, why?
```

Comment: `\fromlist` is not expandable (for example, try `\edef\tmp{\fromlist{{1in,2in,3in}}{2}}`).  Thus, `\rule` doesn't see the final result for use as its input, and coughs an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You need to extract the item by expansion, you can not make assignments within the argument to `\rule`. Fortunately LaTeX provides such a function out of the box in the `clist` (comma list) module. More exactlythe `nn` variant is available, which would work for the explicit list, if you need to expand commands holding a list, you can declare an `ee` variant as here for the second example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\clist_item:nn{ee}
\newcommand\fromlist{\clist_item:ee}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mylist{1in,2in,3in}
\begin{document}


\rule{\fromlist{1in,2in,3in}{2}}{5pt} 

\rule{\fromlist{\mylist}{3}}{5pt} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

When we say that “a command is (fully) expandable” we mean that it delivers the intended result by performing no assignment or typesetting instruction (among which there is `\relax`).

So your `\bbb` works, because its *expansion* is a length. TeX knows that the first argument to `\rule` should contain a (rigid) length, and it performs macro expansion until finding something that fits the requirement.

When TeX sees your `\fromlist`, it realizes it's not a length, so it does an expansion and it sees `\foreach`. If you do

```
latexdef -p pgffor -s foreach
```

from a terminal, you'll get

```
% pgffor.code.tex, line 60:
\let\foreach=\pgffor@foreach

% pgffor.code.tex, line 45:
\def\pgffor@foreach{%
    \pgffor@atbeginforeach%
    \let\pgffor@assign@before@code=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\pgffor@assign@after@code=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\pgffor@assign@once@code=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\pgffor@remember@code=\pgfutil@empty%
    \let\pgffor@remember@once@code=\pgfutil@empty%
    \pgffor@alphabeticsequencefalse%
    \pgffor@contextfalse%
    %
    \let\pgffor@var=\pgfutil@empty
    %
    \pgffor@vars%
}
```

and you know that your plan is doomed, because even if `\pgffor@atbeginforeach` is expandable (it isn't actually), a bunch of `\let` instructions follows and one is already too many.

Is it necessary to run `latexdef` to see whether a command is expandable or not? Not really. In general you should not expect a command is expandable, unless somebody tells you it is.

And among the `expl3` functions, you can spot those that are (fully) expandable because their name is followed by a star (filled or hollow). The descriptions are found in [`interface3.pdf`](https://texdoc.org/serve/interface3/0).

Your input is a comma separated list of items, so it fits the syntax of a `clist`. And yes, the function `\clist_item:nn` has the star after it! So you might do

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fromlist \clist_item:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but then you'll ask a new question because something like

```
\def\ccc{1pt,2pt,3pt}
\rule{\fromlist\ccc{2}}{3cm}
```

doesn't work. How can you accommodate both implicit and explicit comma lists?

My suggestion is to define `\fromlist` with a *-variant that accepts an implicit list:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fromlist}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% there is *
    \clist_item:Nn #2 { #3 }
   }
   {% no *
    \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

A full example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fromlist}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% there is *
    \clist_item:Nn #2 { #3 }
   }
   {% no *
    \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mylist}{1in,2in,3in}

\begin{document}

\rule{\fromlist{1in,2in,3in}{2}}{5pt}

\rule{\fromlist*{\mylist}{3}}{5pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And `\usepackage{xparse} needed?

Comment: If the delimiter of a list is `:`, `not comma`, how to do it?

Comment: @lyl You basically have to redefine all the clist business for colon-separated lists.

Comment: in my Miktex,  `\usepackage{xparse}` has to be added to your code, or it will fail to run. Does that mean I lost some packages in my system?

Comment: @lyl You should update.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, `\fromlist` is not expandable (for example, try `\edef\tmp{\fromlist{{1in,2in,3in}}{2}}`). Thus, `\rule` doesn't see the final result of `\fromlist`, for use as its input.  It therefore throws an error.

A different approach is proposed below, using `listofitems`, to read and parse the list.  Then, particular entries from the list can be expandably recalled.  The key is to read the list before passing a list element to `\rule`.

I first show it as a two step process with `\readlist` followed by `\rule`.  Alternatively, one can place those two steps in a macro `\Zrule`, as I do in the second approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\newcommand\Zrule[3]{%
  \readlist\rulearg{#1}%
  \rule{\rulearg[#2]}{#3}
}
\begin{document}

\readlist\rulelen{1cm,2.4cm,3cm}
\rule{\rulelen[2]}{5pt}

\Zrule{1in,2in,3in}{2}{5pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful solution! ! And how to determine if a macro is expandable? Why is my `fromlist` non-expandable?

Comment: @lyl `\foreach` isn't expandable (you would need to see the pgf documentation you coulduse an expl3  expandable function to access a list item as shown previously, but even if the loop macro were xpandable `\foreach` puts each item in a group and you make an assignmnt to `\x` and assignments are not expandable. You need `\rule{1in}`  but effectively have `\rule{ { \def\x{1in} } \x }` which can not work.

Comment: As for `listofitems`, is there any way to modify an item of the list? For example, `\readlist\mylist{a,b,c}`, how to change the second item to `d`, then get the list `{a,d,c}`?

Comment: @lyl I'm afraid `listofitems` does not provide that feature, but another package, `readarray` (https://ctan.org/pkg/readarray) has some of those features, though it is primarily intended for 2-D and 3-D arrays.

Comment: @lyl here is one way to do it with `readarray`: `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\def\z{1cm,2.4cm,3cm}
\readarray\z\rulelen[-,1]

\rule{\rulelen[2,1]}{5pt}

\setvalue\rulelen[2,1]{6cm}

\rule{\rulelen[2,1]}{5pt}
\end{document}`

Comment: Many thanks for your info!!

Answer (score 2):

This s a variant

```
\fromlist{⟨tokens to prepend to i-th comma-list-item⟩}%
         {⟨tokens to append to i-th comma-list-item⟩}%
         {⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity of value i⟩}%
         {⟨comma-list⟩}
```

which—within the local scope of the *i*-th `\foreach`-iteration—does

`⟨tokens to prepend to i-th comma-list-item⟩{⟨i-th comma-list-item⟩}⟨tokens to append to i-th comma-list-item⟩`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}
\newcommand\fromlist[4]{%
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in #4{%
    \ifnum\i=\expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\number#3} %
    \expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
    {%
      \breakforeach
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\x}{#1}#2%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

List provided explicitly:

\fromlist{\rule}{{5pt}}{1}{{1in,2in,3in}}

\fromlist{\rule}{{5pt}}{2}{{1in,2in,3in}}

\fromlist{\rule}{{5pt}}{3}{{1in,2in,3in}}

\newcommand\commalist{1in,2in,3in}

List provided via macro:

\fromlist{\rule}{{5pt}}{1}{\commalist}

\fromlist{\rule}{{5pt}}{2}{\commalist}

\fromlist{\rule}{{5pt}}{3}{\commalist}

\end{document}
```

[image]